# How to get document ID or URL without access to DocumentApp?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a document in Google Drive which is an uploaded DOCX - because of this I have no access to DocumentApp.

I need to find out the document ID, which I know is in the URL, but all the examples of actually getting the current document URL require DocumentApp.

Is there a way to get the URL (e.g. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wbcsSlMYp5WEZjSffAqLRfqvZ2CpZnxo/edit) without DocumentApp?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `get the URL (e.g. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wbcsSlMYp5WEZjSffAqLRfqvZ2CpZnxo/edit) without DocumentApp`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: do a file.list in google drive and search for the file when you find it it will return your file id.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thanks, I think I've hit another roadblock anyway - can you confirm that it is still true that AppScript add ons don't work from inside DOCX files anyway?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that it has to be Google docs convert it